# Using strtok twice to separate a line into "words" and the "words" into smaller words?

Tags: c, string, strtok

I've got a text file that looks something like this

```
44,12,4,5 2,45,3,1,2,45 6,77,5,3,5,44
```

I would like to use strtok() to separate this file into just numbers and read them into a char**, with spaces included, such that

```
arr[0] = "44"
arr[1] = "12"
arr[2] = "4"
arr[3] = "5"
arr[4] = " "
arr[5] = "2"
...
```

This is my code so far:

```
    int i = 0;
    char line[6000], **arr = calloc(200, sizeof(char*)), *token = calloc(50, sizeof(char)), *token2 = calloc(8, sizeof(char));
    FILE* textFile = openFileForReading(); //Simple method, works fine.
    fgets(line, sizeof line, textFile);
    token = strtok(line, " ");
    token2 = strtok(token, ",");
    arr[i] = token2;
    while((token2 = strtok(NULL, ",")) != NULL)
    {
            i++;
            arr[i] = token2;
    }

    i++;
    arr[i] = " "; //adds the space once we're done looping through the "word"

    while((token = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL) //PROGRAM BREAKS HERE
    {
            token2 = strtok(token, ",");
            i++;
            arr[i] = token2;
            while((token2 = strtok(NULL, ",")) != NULL)
            {
                    i++;
                    arr[i] = token2;
            }
            i++;
            arr[i] = " ";
    }
```

At the beginning of the second `while` loop, it's never executed. I'm sure it's got something to do with passing a `NULL` argument into strtok, but I'm not sure really how to get around this. If any of you folks have advice, suggestions, or critique, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: `strtok` will not work because it keeps hidden state between calls. POSIX has `strtok_r` which will work because it has no hidden state.

Comment: [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) is not reentrant, you can't use it to parse more than one string. Some systems have a reentrant `strtok_r` function, but it's not portable. Best (portable) solution is to do it in two passes.

Comment: You can use `strcspn` instead of `strtok`. The difference is that `strcspn` won't modify the input string, so you can examine the location where it found the delimiter, to see whether it's a comma or a space. Then you can write the `'\0'` to terminate the substring.

Comment: Windows has `strtok_s()` which is compatible except in name with POSIX `strtok_r()`, and is mostly unrelated to the `strtok_s()` defined in C11 Annex K (though the function in Annex K was designed using the Windows version as a starting point).

Answer (score 1):

`strtok()` maintains state between calls when it's parsing a single string, so it can't be used as you've outlined above.

You have two choices:  either use `strtok_r()` which is re-entrant and therefore can be used as you've written, or use `strtok()` but complete the initial parse into space separated lists first, then iterate over the resulting strings, treating them as comma separated numbers.